# Angular 1.5 and ES6 - importing module

Tags: angularjs, es6-shim

I'm trying to get my head around using the new capabilities in Angular 1.5 and also using Webpack and ES6 via Babel.

In one case, I want to bring in a module (ngStorage), but ngStorage is written in classic 1.x style. So this file:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngStorage from 'ngstorage';
import UserSettings from './user-settings';
import UserFactory from './user.factory';

let userModule = angular.module('user', [ngStorage])

    .service('UserSettings', UserSettings)
    .factory('User', UserFactory);

export default userModule;
```

results in this error at runtime:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module user due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"_invokeQueue":[["$provide","provider",{"0":"$localStorage"}],["$provide","provider",{"0":"$sessionStorage"}]],"_configBlocks":[],"_runBlocks":[],"requires":[],"name":"ngStorage"} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

I'm guessing that I just can't import from ngstorage - it doesn't export anything. Is there a way I can shim 1.x dependencies in order to import them?

Comment: import 'ngstorage'; angular.module('user', ['ng-storage']) should work

Comment: Yes, so simple. Import makes the file available, then we add to the dependency array as usual. Thank you.

Comment: Usually the convention is to export module `name` property and `import` a string that is equal to module name. Notice that [the module](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/master/ngStorage.js) exports Angular object, not ngStorage module itself. In this case it should be just `import 'ngstorage'`.

Comment: As @PetrAveryanov said, `import 'ngstorage'` works but the correct name of the local storage module today is `ngStorage`, so `angular.module('user', ['ngStorage'])` works like a charm.